# JQuery load event

Tags: jquery

I want to run a function when elements of a certain class are loaded and clicked... so something like:

```
$(".blah").on("load,click", function() {
    // do stuff
})
```

but it seems that the `load` event is not an event (maybe?). What's the best way to get the function to run on click and on load?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could trigger the click on document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   $('.blah').click(function() {
       // handle click event
   });
   $('.blah').trigger('click');
});
```

From the jQuery documentation for `load`:

> The load event is sent to an element when it and all sub-elements have
> been completely loaded. This event can be sent to any element
> associated with a URL: images, scripts, frames, iframes, and the
> window object.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a load event. You code don't work because you need comma between events. It should be like this: "load click".

But I think you need a click be triggered only after the element is loaded, so it should be like this:

```
$(".blah").load(function() {        
    $(this).bind("click", function() {
        // do stuff
    })
})
```

Note that if you are loading images it may not work

Caveats of the load event when used with images:

```
It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the same src as before
It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's cache
```

http://api.jquery.com/load-event/